# Is the Expo push notification Tool good for productions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am developing a backend api in NodeJS to send notifications to a mobile application made with expo/react native. So far I have managed to connect to the expo push notification tool from the NodeJS api and was able to push notifications to an Android Studio emulator. But I want to make sure that when I build my app for production, the Expo push notification tool will still work. Does anyone have any idea if my reasoning is correct? Or should I switch to google firebase server?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

It's not good to use push expo notifications. In place of that, you can use AWS API gateway WebSocket.[Please refer this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api.html)

Comment: Can u explain the what u mean exactly? how to use it?

Comment: You can use dynamodb, Lambda, and API gateway to publish and store notifications.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).